# Integrate $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ over the region $0 \leq r \leq 4, \pi/4 \leq \theta \leq3\pi/4, -1\leq z \leq1.$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, cylindrical-coordinates

The question says to evaluate the given triple integral in cylindrical coordinates over the region $W$. Here's the integrand and the region: [image]

I'm confused about this question because I keep getting $0$. Here's the triple integral in polar coordinates that represents the region given in question $9$:

Note that I use $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$, and $z=z$ to simplify the integrand $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$.

$$\int_{-1}^1\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}\int_{0}^4 r(r^2+z^2) \ dr\ d\theta \ dz$$

After integrating the inner intergral we end up with positive powers of $r$. As a result, the function evaluated at $1$ minus the function evaluated at $-1$ ends up being $0$, and the integration stops there. The order of integration turns out not to matter: I always get this result.

Yet the text shows a non-zero number as the answer. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is non-zero. I suspect you're calculating the integrals incorrectly, since your setup looks great. We have
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^1\int_{\pi/4}^{3\pi/4}\int_{0}^4 r\big(r^2+z^2\big) \ dr\ d\theta \ dz
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-1}^1\int_0^4\big(r^3+rz^2\big)\,dr\,dz\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-1}^1\left(\frac{r^4}{4}+\frac{r^2z^2}{2}\right)\bigg|_{0\to 0}^4\,dz\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_{-1}^1\left(64+8z^2\right)dz\\
&=\pi\int_{0}^1\left(64+8z^2\right)dz\quad\text{(even function on symmetric interval)}\\
&=\pi\left(64z+\frac{8z^3}{3}\right)\bigg|_{0}^{1}\\
&=\frac{200\pi}{3}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps a lot! I was going wrong in multiple places during my calculation. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Not true...
$$
\int_{0}^4 r(r^2+z^2)dr=\left[\frac{r^4}{4} + \frac{r^2 z^2}{2}\right]_{0}^4 = 
\frac{4^4}{4} + \frac{4^2 z^2}{2}=64+8z^2
$$

Comment: Sorry, I meant for that $dz$ to be a $dr$; I've fixed it now. So you'd actually be evaluating $r^4 + (r^2z^2)/2$ over $1$ and $-1$ with respect to $r$. The positive powers of $r$ in that integrand make it so that the entire thing has the same value whether you're evaluating for $1$ or $-1$

Comment: @JamesRonald When you exchange the order of integration you must be consistent in the integration limits. If you start with $dr$, the integration limits are $0,4$, not $-1,1$.

Comment: Indeed, I fixed that as well, thank you. Do you know how to solve this now that we're evaluating with respect to $r$ first?

Comment: @JamesRoland The result is $\frac{200 \pi}{3}$, regardless of the integration order.

Comment: Right, but how do we get that...?

Comment: @JamesRoland we are talking about integrating polynomials... Did you actually try to evaluate the integral? what are you doubts, specifically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99559/discussion-between-pierrecarre-and-james-ronald).